# hstore_to_map command syntax

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, expression, syntax

I am struggling with the correct `hstore_to_map` syntax. I extracted power plants from OSM. In the "other tags" field are coal, hydro, solar stated as sources. How do I get/display just the coal power plants ? I use QGIS 3.22 LTR.

Comment: I just found `explode Hstore field` in the toolbox of QGIS. This works too, extracts the tags into the corresponding fields. But it would be still helpfull to know how to select from a Hstore field without exploding it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this expression in "Select Features by Expression (Ctrl+F3)" to select coal power plants.

```
map_get(
  hstore_to_map(other_tags),
  'plant:source') = 'coal'    -- change 'plant:source' and 'coal' if necessary
```